# Delphi XE2: Looking for faster way to migrate VCL ProjectGroup from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

As stated in [RAD Studio docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Migrating_VCL_Applications_to_Cross-Platform), to migrate 32 bit VCL application to 64 bit:

> Open your 32-bit application in the IDE, add and activate the 64-bit target platform, and compile your application as a 64-bit application.

I have a project group that contain more than 200 32-bits projects.  In order to support 64 bits, I need to add the 64 bit target platform one by one.

Is there a faster way to add 64 bit target platform ?

Comment: can targets be defined in option sets?

Comment: DPROJ files are just XML files. If you don't write an XML diff utility to figure it out, let me know and I will write one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would have to write (or find) a utlity app that loops through the .dproj files of the Project Group updating the settings as needed.  There is no built-in functionality to automate that.

Comment: Although not yet for this purpose, we use Funduc Search & Replace to update delphi project files, doing things like altering search paths and version info, when we create new branches.  Sounds like a good job for that utility.  http://www.funduc.com/search_replace.htm

Comment: Just for the record the entry you want to change is:           <Platform value="Win64">False</Platform> to make it
<Platform value="Win64">True</Platform>

Answer (score 10):

As per the release notes, the [JCL 2.3.1.4197](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) version includes a new unit **JclMsBuild** to query and update MsBuild files. Maybe this unit can be used to write a simple upgrade tool.